# how to add image and vector layer for adding points using open layers in angular

Tags: angular, openlayers

This code shows how can add an image to an open layer's map, project it, then add a vector layer to add points to it. I hope this helps if you are using open layers in your project.
Also add interactions to update the marker names. This some extra text to help me meet the minimum characters

```
public map!: Map
ngOnInit(): void { 
 this.map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new ImageLayer({
          source: new Static({
            url: "http://"
            projection: this.projection,
            imageExtent: this.extent
          }),
        }),
        this.vector = new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            url: this.url,
            format: new GeoJSON(),
          }),
          style: this.pointStyleFunction,
        }),
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        projection: this.projection,
        center: getCenter(this.extent),
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 8,
      }),
    });

  }
  pointStyleFunction(feature) {
    return new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)' }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 1 }),
      }),
      text: new Text({
        font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
        text: feature.get('name'),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'black',
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'white' }),
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
      })
    });
  }
}
```

just giving an example for folks who are using angular and open layers.